# How to get REST Api in Ember JS?

Tags: ember.js

I work with an Ember boilerplate that works with REST Api.

The data should be recieved from Laravel backend and rendered in an Ember template. I will be grateful for any help.

Here is response of index (/) route:

```
{
    "responce":[
        {
            "id":0,
            "title":"main",
            "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae, aliquam."
        },
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"about",
            "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, obcaecati? Accusantium ex dolorum voluptate deleniti?"
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "name":"contacts",
            "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates voluptatibus exercitationem molestias rem."
        }
    ]
}
```

I suppose that there should be some kind of a loop that processes the received data and renders it. The result should be something like this:

```
<h3>main</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae, aliquam.</p>
<h3>about</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, obcaecati? Accusantium ex dolorum voluptate deleniti?</p>
<h3>contacts</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates voluptatibus exercitationem molestias rem.</p>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you went through the ember guides?

Comment: Also: ember routes have nothing to do with your backend/api routes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of pieces to put together here, but let me try and layout the general path. Your Laravel API provides structured data that needs to be read by your ember application. Start by setting up your ember routes model hook to read that data. You'll want to check [the guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/getting-started/intro/) for a lot more information, but I would start with [this](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_fetch-example) in your `index` route as the first step:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import fetch from 'fetch';

export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    //this is where your ember app gets data from your API
    return fetch('YOUR-LARAVAL-API.com/index').then(response => {
      console.log(data);
      const data = response.json();
      return data.responce;
    });
  }
});
```

This should make the data available in your `index.hbh` template so you can access it as `model` like:

```
<pre>
{{#each this.model as |post|}}
  <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
  <p>{{post.content}}</p>
{{/each}}
</pre>
```

Comment: Glad I could help, please mark this as the correct answer so it doesn't show up as unresolved anymore.